# MySQL insert exceeding memory. Do I use a php script to send data in chunks?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

```
INSERT INTO events (venue_id, artist_id, name, description)
SELECT e.id, e.artist_id, d.a_song, d.a_lyrics
FROM dump_sql AS d
    INNER JOIN events AS e
    ON d.a_album = e.name
```

Above is the mysql query I am using...works fine. Problem is that I have way too much data (150k records) that is too much it appears for the amount of the memory the server or mysql will allow.

I *think* at a minimum I need a php script to insert the data in chunks and perhaps increasing the memory allowance in the php, mysql and ???

Any and all help here would be most appreciated...I am a php newb and could use some help coming up with a script or any other pointers.

Thank you!

Error:

Node 0 DMA32 free:2776kB min:2788kB low:3484kB high:4180kB active_anon:211288kB inactive_anon:211276kB active_file:16kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):128kB isolated(file):0kB present:500960kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:116kB shmem:12kB slab_reclaimable:11372kB slab_unreclaimable:32752kB kernel_stack:904kB pagetables:10656kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:640 all_unreclaimable? yes
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Node 0 DMA: 12*4kB 22*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 1*256kB 1*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2016kB
Node 0 DMA32: 676*4kB 12*8kB 4*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2864kB
5001 total pagecache pages
4940 pages in swap cache
Swap cache stats: add 1565880, delete 1560940, find 743932/825587
Free swap  = 0kB
Total swap = 1044216kB
131071 pages RAM
5577 pages reserved
2405 pages shared
118768 pages non-shared
Out of memory: kill process 24373 (httpd) score 410236 or a child
Killed process 24373 (httpd) vsz:1640944kB, anon-rss:345220kB, file-rss:28kB

Comment: What **actuall** issue do you experience? **Always** include original error message in the question

Comment: get the number of records from dump_sql, split it into chunks of say 20k, add another condition to your SELECT statement WHERE (( d.id >= [CHUNK START ID] ) AND ( d.id <= [CHUNK END ID] )), have fun!

Comment: would it be possible to use the explode() php function to split up the data into an array? Then you could use a loop to send all the bits and pieces one at a time. It might take a little longer than it would to send it as a giant chunk, but I can't think of another way.

Comment: @Dorin Duminica: your advice makes no sense. `INSERT ... SELECT` doesn't fetch any rows to the client

Comment: @Different55: what data are you talking about? OP performs `INSERT ... SELECT`, so all the data is **already** in the databse

Comment: @zerkms point is that the OP wants to insert too many records, or so says MySQL, 'SELECT e.id, e.artist_id, d.a_song, d.a_lyrics' should give you a HUGE hint... your CV says 7 years experience, I would be surprised if in those 7 years you have never came across a similar issue

Comment: @Dorin Duminica: can you find exact **mysql** message that states about **too many records** please? `INSERT ... SELECT` just cannot throw such errors, since it doesn't read all the result set into the memory - it just processes it row by row. It just will take much time, but will not throw error. Anyway, waiting for your proofs ps: 150k rows is just nothing, it cannot be treated as huge

Comment: @everyone...thank you. Error posted above.

Comment: @zerkms what you're saying is correct partially, but read the question again, he just edited and added the error which clearly says 'Out of memory', so, I believe it has something to do with the settings... anyhu', one way to overcome this is using my first comment, it involves a bit more lines of code, but it will solve the issue. Also, note the "venue_id" <- this means that the data is being fed from multiple venues, which can mean anything from 2 to n, a lot of events and a lot of sql dumps.

Comment: @Dorin Duminica: can you please point me where was I wrong? He posted some dump that states that probably some **3rd party** daemon or kernel process killed **httpd** (`Out of memory: kill process 24373 (httpd)`). How is it related to mysql itself?? As I said - `INSERT ... SELECT` reads row by row and 150k **is not huge** amount of rows at all

Comment: @user1114330 what configuration does the server have and how many venues do you expect to connect to the server?

Comment: Ouch..Im sorry venue_id was a typo..should be event_id.

Comment: Also..what do you exactly need to know about the server configs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the default value of

> max_allowed_packet

in my.ini.

Change it to something like:

> max_allowed_packet = 100M

and see if that helps.

Comment: `max_allowed_packet` relies on the amount of data sent from client to the server. In this case client only sends the query of 100 bytes long, nothing more